# How to have an integrated view of what are changes in a branch compared with the parent node it is branched from

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-extensions

My case is that I have a branch by another person, which is really large and contains tens of commits with each commits containing up to tens of file.

I normally view the changes made by a branch in Bitbucket. There, it can show me an integrated view of what is changed in a branch compared with the parent commit where the branch comes from.

However, when the changes are too large and many, BitBucket failed to show that with an error message "The merge is too large to display".

I am now using Git Extensions to view the branch. I can view the commits at the branch one by one but I cannot find a way to have an integrated view of what are the changes made at the branch.

As it is a big change, some lines are added/amended at one commit and reverted at another commit. Viewing them one by one is meaningless and time-consuming.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The merge is too large to display" appears on a Merge Request, with a target branch to merge to. I will assume that target branch is `master`, just change that name if you need to.

---

You can open a visual viewer to see that diff from the command line :

```
git difftool -d master...branch    # three dots notation
```

This command will find the so called *merge base* between `master` and `branch`, and open the diff between that merge base, and `branch`.

---

For this specific action, I'm not sure `Git Extensions` will offer much in terms of features :

you could spot the merge base in the history viewer, right click and select "Compare with ...", then compare it with the head of `branch`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, you are right that the target branch is master. But as the master branch is also updated by others, and I need to compare the different between master commit where my branch was branch (not master tip) and my branch tip.

Comment: You are asking for the diff between the merge base and your branch's tip, that's what the three dots will give you.